# How to connect to local network website from android phone

Tags: android, web, server, local

I have a local web site (server) on my local network, and I can connect to it via my PC browser, but not my android phone?  Yes my phone is connected to the local wifi network.  But every time I type in http://192.168.x.x i.e. the ip of the local web server... I get an instant time out error.  This is bull, the local web server is up it is using port 80, is running of course.  This can't be that complicated.  The more I use a smart phone the more I feel it is PITA, at this point, and this is another example of course.  And, yes, I have read the other similar questions... they are useless, suggestions that don/t work... you cannot access the local network from chrome or the stupid samsung browser either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is that the phone is connected to the wrong network. Check if it is connected to the appropriate Wi-Fi router.

Comment: Yup... I had to disconnect from WiFi and reconnect.  Makes no sense, but that was it.  After some additional testing, apparently my specific phone/android/prepaid will NOT automatically reconnect to WiFi even when configured (correctly) to do so.  I may NEVER use a prepaid phone from tracfone again.. keep running into all kinds of restrictions and locked down options.